# DevOps pipeline System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: azure-pipelines, devops, octopus-deploy

I have created a new pipeline which is intended to fetch a Git repo and push a package to Octopus.

The problem is it is failing at the Octopus package step with a `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException`.

In the previous .NET core Publish step the files are being dropped to the location

```
'C:\vstsagent\vsts-agent-win-x86-2.142.1\_work\35\\**s**\\MyProject.csproj'
```

But the octopus step is looking in

```
'C:\vstsagent\vsts-agent-win-x86-2.142.1\_work\35\\**a**\\MyProject'
```

The difference being between the directories '**s**' and '**a**'.

We have a number of other pipelines in DevOps and I have compared this to a similar one and can find no differences except the project name.

Answer (score 1):

The **s** folder is where the source code is checkout out either on the root folder or under other folders if you multi checkout repositories (s/repo1 , s/repo2)

The **a** folder is `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory` and it is a special purpose folder on which many tasks can output their results.

You should either change the publish task to a specific location or the octopus step to read from the s folder.

You could also use a powershell to recursively copy contents of a folder to s and the problem could be resolved.

```
Copy-Item "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/*" -Destination "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)" -Recurse
```

The best option is to implement using the Octopus and build tasks and not by using powershell.

More information about pre defined variables on Azure DevOps:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Thank you.
In my publish task I have the arguments 
--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
Which, reading your answer suggests that it publishes to the "a" directory.
In the Octopus Package step the source path is
$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\MyProject
Which looks like the same location, so I am a little confused!

Comment: I cannot be sure of the certain project but the things you describe should work. You could try a different agent type maybe windows, linux to determine if is the same behavior.